# Convert Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Can anybody help to convert this `objective-c` code into `swift`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
for (NSString *key in trDict) {
    [data setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d", key, i] forKey:key];
}
```

Some Suggested?
Thanks.

Comment: I edited and put what I felt. But where there are question marks do not know what to put

Comment: With your edit, this question is 100 times better than it was.

Comment: Do you still need this as an NSMutableDictionary? Or would you be okay with a "normal" Swift dictionary?

Comment: do you think that `setValue(_ forUndefinedKey:)` matched `-setValue:forKey:`?

Comment: @Hemang when i put "key" get me a error : Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of type '(StringLiteralConvertible, forUndefinedKey: (key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject))'   And as I revenue "value"

Comment: What's your "i" variable?

Comment: Your trDict above comes from heaven. Or hell?

Comment: I edited with the block complete code

Answer (score 2):

You can use this loop to get the data and keys:

```
var data = Dictionary<String, String>()
for (key, obj) in trDict {
    data[key] =  "\(key), \(obj)"
}
```

You cannot get index from dictionary because dictionary is unordered collection

Answer (score 1):

This is information that is available in the "Introduction to Swift" in the book released (for free) by Apple.

```
var dataDictionary: [String, String] = [:]

for (key, value) in trDict {
    dataDictionary[key] = "\(key) \(value)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock` method to enumerate `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
var data = NSMutableDictionary(capacity: 2) as NSMutableDictionary!
data.setValue("Value1", forKey: "Key1")
data.setValue("Value2", forKey: "Key2")

data.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock { (key, obj, stop) -> Void in
    var string = "\(key) \(obj)"
    data.setValue(string as String, forKey: string)
}
```